# How can I do to use hour using Google Sheets?

Tags: datetime, google-sheets, time, google-sheets-formula

I have a problem using Google Sheets,

when I type 15 for example and I set the format to hour I get 14/01/1900 00:00:00 whereas I would like to have 15:00:00. How can I do this?

Comment: Time is a fraction of a day, and a day is typically a full integer 1 in both Excel and GS. Hence why your return is `14/1/1900...` You could try: `=TIME(15,0,0)` or `=(1/24)*15`

Comment: There is a function hour().

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You could set some conditional formatting to do that, but depends on what you want.

Answer (score 1):

to get hours you need to type:

```
15:00
```

if you type 15 in a cell you can convert it in another cell like this:

[image: 0]

note that if you want to type something into cell and set formatting to Time, you need to type:

```
0.625
```

which becomes `15:00` after you set formatting to Time

[image: 0]

Comment: It may be worth noting that we arrive at 0.625 by dividing 15 by the number of hours in a day (24). So, to get `15:00:00` in a cell, one could also just use `=15/24`, then format it as time.